# Can I safely use the engine and memory clock ranges of my video card?

Tags: graphics-card, amd-radeon, overclocking

I use atitweak, which is basically just a command line interface for the AMD ADL OverDrive5 interface.

```
baarn@manticore ~/git/adl3 $ ./atitweak -l
0. AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series (:0.0)
    engine clock range is 150 - 1200MHz
    memory clock range is 75 - 1575MHz
    core voltage range is 0.8 - 1.25VDC
    performance level 0: engine clock 300MHz, memory clock 150MHz, core voltage 0.95VDC
    performance level 1: engine clock 900MHz, memory clock 1250MHz, core voltage 1.25VDC
    fan speed range: 0 - 100%,  700 - 5900 RPM
```

As you can see there are several ranges the GPU can be over- or underclocked to.

I think of overclocking, as my card doesn't seem to reach it's full potential:

```
baarn@manticore ~/git/adl3 $ ./atitweak -s
0. AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series (:0.0)
    engine clock 900MHz, memory clock 1250MHz, core voltage 1.25VDC, performance level 2, utilization 100%
    fan speed 47% (2092 RPM) (default)
    temperature 69 C
    powertune 0%
```

As both temperature and fan speed are far below maximum, but utilization is at 99% I think I have some room to play around. Are the above ranges - especially engine and memory - safe to use, without frying the card instantly?